# Does IES light work with Eevee in Blender 2.8?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I can use IES in cycles, but seems not work in eevee, there is just no light
Do I have to specifically set up something ??

Comment: Ies does not work in Eevee at the moment

Comment: That's sad, but thanks for the anwser :)